# Sum all max elements of each row of a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, max, bubble-sort

I am trying to make a function that prints the sum of all max elements of each row. I wrote a function that prints 5 max elements of a 2D array, and to calculate the sum I need to put all max elements into one array. Now I have no idea why my code shows me incorrect values, I'll appreciate any help you can give.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MATRIX_SIZE 5


void bubleSort(int arr[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++)
    {
      for (int h = j + 1; h < MATRIX_SIZE; h++)
      {
        if (arr[j][i] > arr[h][i])
        {
          int tmp = arr[j][i];
          arr[j][i] = arr[h][i];
          arr[h][i] = tmp;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

int find_max_sum(int arr[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE]) 
{
  int sum = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++) 
  {
    int max = arr[i][0];
    for (int j = 1; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++) 
    {
      if (max < arr[i][j]) 
      {
        max = arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    printf("%d-th row max = %d\n", i + 1, max);
    sum += max;
  }
  return sum;
}


int printing(int arr[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++)
    {
      printf("%5.0d", arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  puts("\n");

  return 0;
}

int main() {

  int arr[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE] = {
    { 12, 7,  23, 13,  4  },
    { 67, 15, 34, -5,  9  },
    { 2,  5,  17, -23, 45 },
    { 26, -6, 23, -5,  -9 },
    { 18, 37, -8, 26,  12 }
  };

  printing(arr);
  printf("\nSum of max elements of 2d array = %d\n", find_max_sum(arr));
  bubleSort(arr);
  printing(arr);
  printf("\nSum of max elements of 2d array = %d\n", find_max_sum(arr));

}
```

(Updated)

I have a task to sort and print max elements of each row and print their sum but I must print it in in a separate function, I must have minimum 3 function - sort, maxElementOfEachRow, Sum(maxElementOfEachRow), so that's why I asked about pushing max elements into an array to use it in the next function Sum or there is another way to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't need to sort to find a maximum. It requires one simple pass of the data.

Comment: Tip: Don't create global constants with names like `n`. That doesn't describe what it is or does or means. Instead use something like `MATRIX_SIZE`.

Comment: In addition, your sort is pointless because in `maxEl` you read through the entire array anyway. Just put `max = arr[i][0];` before the inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to sort the elements to get the max of a row.
Selecting max element from an array(unordered) is O(n) operation, whereas
 sorting the array takes O(n^2) time (in case of bubble sort) and O(nlogn) if you use quicksort or mergesort.
Here's the solution without sorting
Hope this helps

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROWS 5
#define COLS 5
void bubbleSort(int arr[ROWS][COLS]) {
  // Sorting in ascending order
  for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < COLS - 1; i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < COLS; j++) {
        if (arr[row][i] > arr[row][j]) {
          int tmp = arr[row][i];
          arr[row][i] = arr[row][j];
          arr[row][j] = tmp;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
void max_element_of_each_row(int arr[ROWS][COLS], int sumArr[ROWS]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    sumArr[i] = arr[i][COLS - 1]; // Last element is the max element
  }
}
int sum_arr(int sumArr[ROWS]) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    sum += sumArr[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
int find_max_sum(int arr[ROWS][COLS]) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    int max = arr[i][0];
    for (int j = 1; j < COLS; j++) {
      if (max < arr[i][j]) {
        max = arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    printf("%dth row max = %d\n", i + 1, max);
    sum += max;
  }
  return sum;
}
void print_max_element_of_each_row(int sumArr[ROWS]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    printf("%dth row max = %d\n", i + 1, sumArr[i]);
  }
}
void print(int arr[ROWS][COLS]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
      printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
void solution2(int arr[ROWS][COLS]) {
  printf("Before sorting\n");
  print(arr);
  bubbleSort(arr);
  printf("After sorting\n");
  print(arr);
  int sumArr[ROWS];
  max_element_of_each_row(arr, sumArr);
  print_max_element_of_each_row(sumArr);
  printf("Sum of max elements of each row: %d", sum_arr(sumArr));
}
void solution1(int arr[ROWS][COLS]) {
  print(arr);
  printf("Max sum of 2d array = %d", find_max_sum(arr));
}
int main() {
  int arr[ROWS][COLS] = {12,  7,  23, 13, 4,  67, 15, 34, -5, 9,  2,  5, 17,
                         -23, 45, 26, -6, 23, -5, -9, 18, 37, -8, 26, 12};
  // solution1(arr);
  solution2(arr);
}
```

Output(for solution1):
12  7   23  13  4   
67  15  34  -5  9   
2   5   17  -23 45  
26  -6  23  -5  -9  
18  37  -8  26  12  
1th row max = 23
2th row max = 67
3th row max = 45
4th row max = 26
5th row max = 37
Max sum of 2d array = 198

Output(for solution2):
Before sorting
12  7   23  13  4   
67  15  34  -5  9   
2   5   17  -23 45  
26  -6  23  -5  -9  
18  37  -8  26  12
 
After sorting
4   7   12  13  23  
-5  9   15  34  67  
-23 2   5   17  45  
-9  -6  -5  23  26  
-8  12  18  26  37  
1th row max = 23
2th row max = 67
3th row max = 45
4th row max = 26
5th row max = 37
Sum of max elements of each row: 198

Comment: That's okay, I've done it before posting this, thank you for an answer.
I am sorting because I have a task to sort and print max elements of each row and print their sum but I must print it in in a separate function, I must have minimum 3 function - sort, maxElementOfEachRow, Sum(maxElementOfEachRow), so that's why I asked about pushing max elements into an array to use it in the next function Sum or there is another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The max of each row, and their sum, can be found in a pair of loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define ROWS 5
#define COLS 5

int main(void) {

    int arr[ROWS][COLS] = {
        { 12, 7,  23, 13,  4  },
        { 67, 15, 34, -5,  9  },
        { 2,  5,  17, -23, 45 },
        { 26, -6, 23, -5,  -9 },
        { 18, 37, -8, 26,  12 }
    };

    int maxsum = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        int rowmax = INT_MIN;
        for(int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            if(rowmax < arr[row][col]) {
                rowmax = arr[row][col];
            }
        }
        printf("Row %d max = %d\n", row + 1, rowmax);
        maxsum += rowmax;
    }
    printf("Sum of max = %d\n", maxsum);
}
```

Program output:

```
Row 1 max = 23
Row 2 max = 67
Row 3 max = 45
Row 4 max = 26
Row 5 max = 37
Sum of max = 198
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MATRIX_SIZE 5

void bubleSort(int arr[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE]) // sorting an array by buble sort in descending order
{
  for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++)
    {
      for (int h = j + 1; h < MATRIX_SIZE; h++)
      {
        if (arr[j][i] < arr[h][i])
        {
          int tempt = arr[j][i];
          arr[j][i] = arr[h][i];
          arr[h][i] = tempt;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

int find_max_elm(int arr[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE], int sumArr[MATRIX_SIZE]) // findind max element in each row of a 2d array
{
  for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
  {
    int max = arr[i][0];
    for (int j = 1; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++)
    {
      if (max < arr[i][j])
      {
        max = arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    sumArr[i] = max;
  }
}

int sum_arr(int sumArr[MATRIX_SIZE]) // calculating the summ of all max elements in each row of a 2d array
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
  {
    sum += sumArr[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

void print_max_element_of_each_row(int sumArr[MATRIX_SIZE]) // printing all max elements in each row of a 2d array
{
  for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
  {
    printf("%d-th row max = %d\n", i + 1, sumArr[i]);
  }
}

int printing(int arr[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE]) // printing an array = matrix
{
  for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++)
    {
      printf("%5.0d", arr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  puts("\n");

  return 0;
}

int main() {

  int arr[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE] = {
    { 12, 7,  23, 13,  4  },
    { 67, 15, 34, -5,  9  },
    { 2,  5,  17, -23, 45 },
    { 26, -6, 23, -5,  -9 },
    { 18, 37, -8, 26,  12 }
  };


  printf("Before sorting\n");
  printing(arr);

  bubleSort(arr);

  printf("After sorting\n");
  printing(arr);

  int sumArr[MATRIX_SIZE];

  find_max_elm(arr, sumArr);
  print_max_element_of_each_row(sumArr);
  printf("\nSum of max elements of each row: %d", sum_arr(sumArr));
}
```